# Problem rendering compound letters in Devanagari and other Indian scripts (for languages - Hindi, Marathi, ...)

Tags: fonts, text, unicode, ubuntu-font-family

I am having trouble getting letters to be rendered properly when created as combinations of two or more partial letters (this is a special feature of some Indian scripts, you can form compound sounds by concatenating parts of individual letters according to some rules).

Here's an example of Hindi and another Indian script:

[image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/psatya/8117393178]

Here's another similar question that has gone unanswered for a long while: [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785599/font-problem-in-ubuntu-16-4-devanagari-hindi-malayalam-fonts-looks-like-spli).

Is there any way to correct or patch this? Perhaps by installing additional fonts/ encoding schemes? Because it renders just fine on Android and other operating systems that I would like to avoid naming.

Comment: Install the fonts that Android uses - the Noto fonts

Comment: @muru, I did follow that post and installed the Noto package. But it still doesn't solve my problem. For example, please see this screenshot: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24pvrxd&s=9#.WRiLYjclHVp

Comment: you'd still have to tell the applications to use the Noto fonts instead, in their font settings

Comment: You're right, I forgot that.

Comment: @muru Marked as duplicate.